# how to invoke jupyter notebook if I've installed python35 and python27

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I have python27 and python35 installed on my mac. I've used alias python2 for python27 and python for python35. When typing "python" in the terminal, python35 shows up.
I also have Anacoda. 
By right I should have pip3 and jupyter notebook installed.

I was trying to use jupyter notebook.
I typed"jupyter notebook" in terminal, I got

```
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

I typed python -m pip install jupyter

```
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in /Users/xxv/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Then I typed: pip3 install jupyter, according to the docs
I got

```
-bash: pip3: command not found
```

pip install jupyter, I got:

```
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/vv/243h_5ks0xs0cmt62rx7swlm0000gn/T/pip-build-VsnCwB/MarkupSafe/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/vv/243h_5ks0xs0cmt62rx7swlm0000gn/T/pip-Fa2r4V-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/vv/243h_5ks0xs0cmt62rx7swlm0000gn/T/pip-build-VsnCwB/MarkupSafe/
```

pip show pip, got:

```
Name: pip
Version: 9.0.1
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: python-virtualenv@groups.google.com
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
Requires:
```

Comment: shouldn't it be : python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install jupyter

Comment: How did you install Python 3.5? It's version of pip probably isn't on your `$PATH`.

Comment: If you have anaconda installed. Try the command :  anaconda-navigator on terminal. It will open the GUI through which you can open jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Your active PIP is for python2.7

```
 Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
```

If you have python3.5, pip would have come automatically with it.
try, 
`python3 -m pip install jupyter` to have jupyter properly installed using python3's PIP.

consider changing your default python and PIP version that gets triggered when you do **python or pip**

you can use alias for doing the above,

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.x'
alias pip='python3 -m pip'
```

Comment: I've updated the post. I have assign alias python2 to python27, python to python35. When I do python -m pip install jupyter, it shows the required package was installed... very confused @Prakash Palnati

Comment: do python and hit enter in the termianl and see which python version shows up.

Comment: your jupyter is installed via anaconda python. `in /Users/xiaoxuefei/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages`. you might have to invoke jupyter via `conda run jupyter notebook` or older version as `conda run ipython-notebook`

Comment: I think we are getting there. when typed conda, it says "conda: command not found"..does it mean "conda" although installed, it is not in my $PATH or something..

Comment: I guess the same.check your `.bashrc` and check for sumthign like these `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda3/bin
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda3/lib`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159363/discussion-between-prakash-palnati-and-lisa).